# Nginx enable direct access only to images

Tags: nginx

I would like to expose files in `/var/files` to the user on `http://myweb.com/img/someimage.jpg` but also to disable accessing non-image files.

This is what I am trying to do, but it does not work, could you help me?

```
    location /img/*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico) {
        alias /var/files;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias), you should be able to match the file name via regex and use it in the `alias` statement, i.e.

```
location ~ /img/(.+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico))$ {
    alias /var/files/$1;
}
```

(That is pretty much one of the examples there ;-)

Comment: It always puts trailing slash at the end 500 Internal Server Error :/

Comment: First, the problem I was facing even while trying all the methods was that chrome stored trailing slash at wrong config and continued adding slash at the end of URL even nginx was fine configured, had to test this in Anonymous window in Chrome. Next there was missing ^ char. `~^/img/`( is correct. Thanks for your help! ;)